# How to set width of cells differently in each row of table, without colspan?

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is ordinary question, I just started learning HTML.
I want each row to be wide 200px;

I want each cell to be wide according to number of cells in the row.
I cant use colspan = "2.5" in first row or colspan ="1.66666" in the second row.

I tried this in css for cells in second row after setting width to tr, doesnt work: width:calc(100%/3);

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>word</td>
    <td> word </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>word</td>
    <td>word</td>
    <td>word</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>word</td>
    <td>word</td>

    <td>word</td>
    <td>word</td>
    <td>word</td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Comment: Is this tabular data (data that makes sense to be in a `<table>`) or are you using a `<table>` to lay out your content on the page?

Comment: What you are describing is not a table. I suggest that you rethink your methodology.

Comment: I can just about imagine a situation where it would make sense to try to do that to a table, but it would be exceedingly rare. It's impossible to tell if it makes sense here because your example code is context-free (we can't tell how the data is supposed to relate since its just *word* repeated over an over). This seems more suited to a series of grids than a table.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain it as simple as I can as you are a very beginner.

You cannot use values like 2.5 or width: calc(100%/3) as row/colspan values.
And if you need to create a grid you should create it using divs and custom CSS. Your code doesn't define a correct table. You are trying to create a grid system. I have recreated what you are trying to accomplish using divs and custom CSS.

```css
.table{
border:1px solid black;
display:grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;}

.table_row{
width:100%;
display: flex;
justify-content:between;
border:1px solid black;
}

.table_column{
width:50%;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
    <div class="table_column"> word </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
    <div class="table_column">word</div>
  </div>
</div>
```